# how to get a String value from a SQL query in Grails?

Tags: sql, string, url, grails, groovy

I need to return a String value so I can build a object from another app via Restful. Part of my code the following snippet follows:

```
def searchProductionOrder (String sequentialNumber) {
    def sql = Sql.newInstance(dbUrl, user, pwd, driverName)
    String idProdOrder = sql.execute("""
        SELECT production_order.idProdOrder
        FROM production_order production_order
        WHERE production_order.sequential_number LIKE ${sequentialNumber}
         """).toString();
    String url = ":8080/app2/api/productionOrder/"+idProdOrder
    // call to Restful service
    return Order
}
```

But the String url is always interpreted (and I printed it for testing) as:

> url: :8080/app2/api/productionOrder/true

I need the idProdOrder String to return its value, not a boolean value. How can I do so?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing execute which will always return a Boolean do something like the following

```
def searchProductionOrder (String sequentialNumber) {
    def sql = Sql.newInstance(dbUrl, user, pwd, driverName)
    String idProdOrders = sql.rows("""
        SELECT production_order.idProdOrder
        FROM production_order production_order
        WHERE production_order.sequential_number LIKE ${sequentialNumber}
         """)
    if(idProdOrders.size()==1)
    {
      String url = ":8080/app2/api/productionOrder/"+idProdOrders[0].idProdOrder
      // call to Restful service
      return Order 
    }
    else
    {
      //You have either no results from the query or more then 1 so do something
    }

}
```

If you wanted to make sure you did something for each result you could use the sql.eachRow as well. The documentation is [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html). Only thing to double check is the name of the entry it returns I'm not sure what it will do since you do production_order.idProdOrder